# How to extract data in the right order with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the [balance sheet](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/balance-sheet?p=MSFT) for an example ticker "MSFT" (Microsoft) from Yahoo Finance.

Using Selenium to click on the button "Expand All" before any scraping is done. This part seems to work.

By the way, when the Chrome web driver is launched, I manually click on the button(s) to accept or reject cookies. In a later step, I plan to add some more code so that this part is also automated. My question is though not on this one now.

Below is how the code currently looks like.

```
# for scraping the balance sheet from Yahoo Finance
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# importing selenium to click on the "Expand All" button before scraping the financial statements
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def get_balance_sheet_from_yfinance(ticker):
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/balance-sheet?p={ticker}"

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3600).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
        By.XPATH, "//section[@data-test='qsp-financial']//span[text()='Expand All']"))).click()

    #content whole page in html format
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    # get the column headers (i.e. 'Breakdown' row)
    div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'D(tbhg)'})
    if len(div) < 1:
        print("Fail to retrieve table column header")
        exit(0)

    # get the list of columns from the column headers
    col = []
    for h in div[0].find_all('span'):
        text = h.get_text()
        if text != "Breakdown":
            col.append(datetime.strptime(text, "%m/%d/%Y"))

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)


    # the following code returns an empty list for index (why?)
    # and values in a list that need actually be in a DataFrame
    idx = []
    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-test': 'fin-row'}):
        for h in div.find_all('title'):
            text = h.get_text()
            idx.append(text)

    val = []
    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-test': 'fin-col'}):
        for h in div.find_all('span'):
            num = int(h.get_text().replace(",", "")) * 1000
            val.append(num)

    # if the above part is commented out and this block is used instead
    # the following code manages to work well until the row "Cash Equivalents" 
    # that is because there are no entries for years 2020 and 2019 on this row
    """ for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-test': 'fin-row'}):
        i = 0
        idx = ""
        val = []
        for h in div.find_all('span'):
            if i % 5 == 0:
                idx = h.get_text()
            else:
                num = int(h.get_text().replace(",", "")) * 1000
                val.append(num)
            i += 1
        row = pd.DataFrame([val], columns=col, index=[idx])
        df = pd.concat([df, row], axis=0) """
    
    return idx, val


get_balance_sheet_from_yfinance("MSFT")
```

I could not get the data scraped from the expanded table in a usable tabular format. Instead, the function above returns what I managed to scrape from the webpage. There are some additional comments in the code.

Could you give me some ideas on how to properly extract the data and put it into a DataFrame object with index which should be the text under the "Breakdown" column? Basically, the DataFrame should look like the snapshot below, with what is under the first column in there being the index.

[balance-sheet-df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS27d.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've spent a long time on this, hope it helps, basically your function now returns a `dataFrame` with the following formatting:

```
                                                  2022-06-29   2021-06-29   2020-06-29   2019-06-29
Total Assets                                     364,840,000  333,779,000  301,311,000  286,556,000
Current Assets                                   169,684,000  184,406,000  181,915,000  175,552,000
Cash, Cash Equivalents & Short Term Investments  104,749,000  130,334,000  136,527,000  133,819,000
Cash And Cash Equivalents                         13,931,000   14,224,000   13,576,000   11,356,000
Cash                                               8,258,000    7,272,000            -            -
...                                                      ...          ...          ...          ...
Tangible Book Value                               87,720,000   84,477,000   67,915,000   52,554,000
Total Debt                                        61,270,000   67,775,000   70,998,000   78,366,000
Net Debt                                          35,850,000   43,922,000   49,751,000   60,822,000
Share Issued                                       7,464,000    7,519,000    7,571,000    7,643,000
Ordinary Shares Number                             7,464,000    7,519,000    7,571,000    7,643,000
```

and here's the final code:

```
# for scraping the balance sheet from Yahoo Finance
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# importing selenium to click on the "Expand All" button before scraping the financial statements
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def get_balance_sheet_from_yfinance(ticker):
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/balance-sheet?p={ticker}"

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3600).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
        By.XPATH, "//section[@data-test='qsp-financial']//span[text()='Expand All']"))).click()

    # content whole page in html format
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    # get the column headers (i.e. 'Breakdown' row)
    div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'D(tbhg)'})
    if len(div) < 1:
        print("Fail to retrieve table column header")
        exit(0)

    # get the list of columns from the column headers
    col = []
    for h in div[0].find_all('span'):
        text = h.get_text()
        if text != "Breakdown":
            col.append(datetime.strptime(text, "%m/%d/%Y"))

    row = {}
    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-test': 'fin-row'}):
        head = div.find('span').get_text()
        i = 4
        for h in div.find_all('span'):
            if h.get_text().replace(',', '').isdigit() or h.get_text()[0] == '-':
                row[head].append(h.get_text())
                i += 1
            else:
                while i < 4:
                    row[head].append('')
                    i += 1
                else:
                    head = h.get_text()
                    row[head] = []
                    i = 0

    for k, v in row.items():
        while len(v) < 4:
            row[k].append('-')

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col, index=row.keys(), data=row.values())
    print(df)
    
    return df
get_balance_sheet_from_yfinance("MSFT")
```

i've removed some od the unused code and added a new scrapping method, but i have kept your method of getting the dates of all the columns.

if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask in the comments.